# I18n for Flowbite popups

Tags: internationalization, svelte, flowbite

I'm working on a Svelte app that could potentially have Spanish speaking users. So far I've happily added the proper I18n material. But I've run into a problem with Flowbite's internal messages. I'm not sure how to adjust them for the selected language. Here's the failed output:

[image]

The relevant code with the problem is this:

```
        <FloatingLabelInput type="email" style="outlined" name="email" required>
            {$_('register.email')}
        </FloatingLabelInput>
```

How do I go about fixing the popup text to be the user's language?

Bonus question: the `FloatingLabelInput` used to be just `Input` and the whole thing expanded properly to the width of the entries below. Any way to fix that?

Comment: I have a quick follow-up: I pulled down the Flowbite and Tailwind projects from github and did a full text search for the text in my example and it's not to be found. This has me completely puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've answered my own question with some further testing. As I said in a previous comment, I couldn't find the text in the github library for either Tailwind or Flowbite. Nor was it being streamed in from any http request. Nor could it be found in the elements. Further, the hover-text for the input fields didn't appear even when setting the `:hover` tag for the field (which would normally trigger any relevant selector). Final conclusion: it's nothing you can get around directly because the browser itself is creating it. Change your O/S to another language and the popups will be in the other language.